# Android: Is there an object in Kotlin that contains all characters like colon, semicolon etc

Tags: android, kotlin, char, constants, character

Right now I am starting a new project and I usually had a constant class for symbols like:

```
object Symbols{
  const val CHAR_COLON = ":"
  const val CHAR_COMMA = ","
  const val CHAR_SEMICOLON = ";"
  etc.
}
```

Would be great if a class like this was already added in Java or Kotlin but I don't seem to find anything like this. Does anyone know of such a thing? Thanks.

Comment: What is "... all characters like colon, semicolon, etc."? That depends on the context. Punctuation only? Punctuation marks only? Everything which is not a letter or digit? For which languages? What about newline, space, tab, etc.? To be used in regular expressions?

Comment: Usually we would use regex for something like this.

Comment: There are probably tens or even hundreds of thousands of chars supported by Kotlin/Java strings. Which ones to expose in such a class?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to define constants for individual characters (just use the `char`, it's a constant!) but the Unicode standard defines a bunch of categories for characters, and you can access those through the Java [`Character` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html), which also has some methods for getting a character's *type*.

Kotlin gives you a [`CharCategory` enum class](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-char-category/) which contains all these categories, and some functions that make it a little easier - for example you can do this:

```
println(CharCategory.OTHER_PUNCTUATION.contains(','))

>> true
```

But for example, `'-'` is *not* in the `OTHER_PUNCTUATION` category, aka category `Po`. That comes under `DASH_PUNCTUATION`, `Pd`. If you notice, all the punctuation category codes start with *P*, so you could do this kind of thing:

```
val punctuationCategories
    = CharCategory.values().filter { it.code.first() == 'P' }
    
val Char.isPunctuation: Boolean get() = punctuationCategories.any { it.contains(this) }

println('-'.isPunctuation)

>> true
```

That's just a basic overview and pointing out this stuff is baked into the Unicode standard - I don't really know a lot about it (I can't see a more convenient way to do this but I could be wrong) and I'm not sure if it's helpful, but there it is!

[Kotlin *does* have an object full of constants](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-typography/) for *"Unicode symbols used in proper Typography"* for some reason though! Also a couple with typos in the name so they had to deprecate them, now that's what I call typography

---

edit: I should point out that Unicode aims to represent every writing system that ever existed, so its scope of what counts as "punctuation" might be a bit broader than what you're looking for! It depends if you're just trying to check a character, or if you want to create a collection of punctuation characters. If you just want to limit things to a particular `Charset`, like `US_ASCII` or whatever, I'm not sure how you can get access to all the characters that covers